# How to take an id document for deletion

Tags: flutter

Help me write a request to delete the selected document from Firestore.
How to select an object that is being deleted via dismissible?

```
return Dismissible(
                  key: ObjectKey(snapshot.data.docs[index]),
                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                  background: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    color: HexColor('#E5213E'),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.delete,
                        color: HexColor('#FFFFFF'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('Costs')
                          .doc()
                          .delete();
                    });
                  },
                  child: _listItem(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]),
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:

```
onDismissed: (direction) {
    snapshot.data.docs[index].reference.delete();
},
```